# Ant classpath build issues in MyEclipse

Tags: java, ant, classpath, myeclipse

I am currently trying to change the spring version of an ant java project but am unable to rebuild the project because after I replace the jars, the build.xml appears to still be dependent on the old jars. The build xml gets references to the jars dynamically so this should not be happening I think, and I was able to build a version of the project with the upgraded spring jars but now when I go back to rebuild, eclipse wants me to use the old jars.

Here is how the jars are added to the classpath (bea.home.lib is the library folder):

```
<taskdef name="wlappc" classname="weblogic.ant.taskdefs.j2ee.Appc">
    <classpath>
        <fileset dir="${bea.home.lib}">
            <include name="**/*.jar"/>
        </fileset>
    </classpath>
</taskdef>
```

and here is the error being displayed when I try to run the build.xml as an ant script:

```
The archive: /PULSE On-Line/must/APP-INF/lib/spring-aop-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar which is referenced by the classpath, does not exist.
```

I don't know what classpath this error is referencing because in the .classpath file for the project there are references to the new spring jars. The old spring jars are not referenced at all in any text in the entire project. Any ideas how I can change this classpath? The most frustrating part of this is that I was able to build it in the past somehow and it worked without this error appearing.

Answer (score 0):

Problem was human error I, I had added the old jars onto the ant classpath via the ant configuration window in eclipse. This classpath was not actually used in compiling but eclipse thought it was used so it wouldn't let me run the build.xml.